# Optional arguments without a default value

Tags: python, function, optional-parameters

The [Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-parameter) for parameters says the following:

> Parameter - A named entity in a function (or method) definition that specifies an argument (or in some cases, arguments) that the function can accept... Parameters can specify both optional and required arguments, as well as default values for **some** optional arguments.

Purely out of curiosity, I am wondering why the word **some** was included. Is it possible to have an optional argument without a default value?

Comment: `*args` and `**kwargs` are optional arguments without default values

Comment: @Pranav Please don't post answers in the comments. If you posted that as an answer, I would upvote :) You don't even need to add anything.

Answer (score 4):

In recent versions you can define functions arguments multiple ways. Here is how they can be defined and called:

```
def fun(a, b, c='foo'):
    ...
fun(1, 2)
fun(1, 2, 'bar')
fun(1, b=2)
fun(1, b=2, c='bar')
fun(a=1, b=2, c='bar')
```

where `a` and `b` are *positional or keyword* args and `c` is an optional *positional or keyword* arg

or

```
def fun(a, b, *, c, d='foo'):
    ...
fun(1, 2, c='bar')
fun(1, b=2, c='bar', d='baz')
fun(a=1, b=2, c='bar', d='baz')
```

where `a` and `b` are *positional or keyword* args and `c` is a *mandatory* kwarg and d is an *optional* kwarg

or

```
def fun(a, b, /, c, *, d, e='foo'):
    ...
fun(1, 2, 3)
fun(1, 2, c=3)
fun(1, 2, c=3, d='bar')
```

where `a` and `b` are *positional only* args, `c` is a *positional or keyword* arg and `d` is a *mandatory* kwarg and `e` is an *optional* kwarg

Comment: On that note, it might be clearer to use different parameter names for each example: `def fun(a, b, c='foo')`, `def fun(d, e, *, f, g='foo')`, and `def fun(h, i, /, j, *, k, m='foo')`, skipping [`l` since it's a bad name](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#names-to-avoid).

Answer (score 2):

The `*` prefix means "arbitrary number of positional parameters", and parameters prefixed by it can be declared without default value.
The word 'some' relates to that reason, you don't have to provide default values for **all** optional arguments.

Answer (score 1):

`*args` and `**kwargs` are optional arguments without default values

*<sub>-- [comment](/questions/67027960/optional-arguments-without-a-default-value#comment118479347_67027960) by [Pranav Hosangadi](/users/843953/pranav-hosangadi)</sub>*